# UISplitViewController and multitasking

Tags: ios, uisplitviewcontroller, multitasking

I'm trying to integrate multitasking in my app and I'm getting a lot of problem cases.

One of them is disabling of automatic collapsing or splitting of the split view controller.
I'm working with iPad air 2. I ran my app, UISplitViewController was the rootViewController for the main window. Then I enabled multitasking by splitting my screen on the two parts. As result UISplitViewController's state became collapsed. Then I logged out in my app and root view controller was changed. After that I expanded my app to whole screen size and again logged in. Split view controller became root view controller again. But despite the fact that it filled full screen size it continues to "think" that it's in collapsed mode. How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you find an answer for this?

Comment: Yep. It seems to me that we remove root view controller and then set new one. But I'm not sure because last half of the year I'm working in other project. I hope I help you.